# How to create all possible subsets of given combination of letters in a list?

Tags: python, string, list

I need help to generate all possible subsets of given letters in Python.
For instance:

```
List=['a','b','c']
Subset=['a','b','c','ab','ac','bc','abc']
```

Comment: please post in algorithm tag, it has very less to do with python 

and see if this helps https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-get-all-subsets-of-given-size-of-a-set/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements)

Answer (score 0):

From the input and output you have given the following code will work for you,

Code:

```
list1=['a','b','c']
sublist = list()
for i in range(len(list1)): 
    for j in range(i+1, len(list1)+1):   
        sub = list1[i:j]
        s1=""
        for j in sub:
            s1+=j   
        sublist.append(s1) 

print(sublist)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'b', 'bc', 'c']
```

1. The above code does not gives all the subset, you may have to modify it as per your requirement